# NodeJS ejs Failed to lookup view "layout" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, layout, ejs

I want to implement my outsourced .ejs files into the layouts/admin.ejs direction. But it throws this error. I want my outsourced header, footer and navbar to be shown. All these files are stored in /views/partials/admin/**filename.ejs**

My layout is in /views/layouts/admin.ejs

```
<%- head -%>


<body>
    <!-- Navigation Top -->
    <%- navigation -%>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container-fluid main">

<%- footer -%>

    </div>

    <script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

so this is my app.js

```
const
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage'),
    Grid = require('gridfs-stream'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 3003;

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('_method')); // Use query string in form

// Set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


// @route get /admin
// @desc route to admin panel
const partialRoute = '/views/partials/';
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('layouts/admin', {
      head: res.sendFile(__dirname + partials + 'head.ejs');
      footer: res.sendFile(__dirname + partials + 'footer.ejs');
      navigation: res.sendFile(__dirname + partials + 'navigaiton.ejs');
  });



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at port ${port}`);
})
```

I tried to change the foldernames and routes and also removed all <% ejs but nothing works [image: structure tree]

Answer (score 0):

hmmm... im using pug and not ejs, but it seems, that the directoryname is wrong/undefined?
You initialize partialRoute, but not partials?

Maybe im blind

```
const partialRoute = '/views/partials/';
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('layouts/admin', {
      head: res.sendFile(__dirname + partials + 'head.ejs');
      footer: res.sendFile(__dirname + partials + 'footer.ejs');
      navigation: res.sendFile(__dirname + partials + 'navigaiton.ejs');
  });
```